# Найти средства выразительности

Tags: стилистика

Я нашел удивительную берестяную трубочку. Меня заинтересовала находка.
Во-первых, в этой трубочке я нашел хороший орех, плотно прихваченный берестой. Но ведь вокруг берез не было орешника. Вероятно, это белка-припасуха, готовясь к долгой зиме, спрятала туда орех.
Разглядывая свою берестяную трубочку, я сделал еще одно открытие. Под прикрытием ореха поселился паучок, и всю внутренность трубочки, ставшей ему зимним домом, он затянул своей паутиной.

Найти языковые средства.

Нашла эпитет (удивительная), слова с уменьшительно-ласкательным  суффиксом (трубочку).
Еще есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не думаю, что трубочку - выразительное средство, это же не отношение к ней, а указание на маленькие размеры.

**поселился** паучок - олицетворение.

белка-припасуха - эпитет.

Эпитеты могут также выражаться существительными, выступающими в качестве приложений или сказуемых, дающих образную характеристику предмета.
Например:  **волшебница**-зима; **мать** — сыра земля; Поэт — это **лира**, а не только **няня** своей души (М. Горький).

Я бы и **ПРИХВАЧЕННЫЙ** назвала эпитетом, потому что прихватить - "схватив, сжать", будто береста схватила и сжала орех, как живое существо, значит, это образное определение, выраженное причастием

белка **"спрятала"** - олицетворение.